# phpoffice\phpspreadsheet - dataseriesvalues -> datasource

Tags: php

If the datasource used to create the chart contains CELL REFERENCES (e.g. `"=B5"`) instead of specific numeric values, the generated XLXS file is corrupted.

Below an image showing the values and the chart :

[image: illustration]

If in `dati1` and `dati2` (the yellow columns) I put CELL REFERENCES instead of values, the file generated is corrupted.

Below, a second image showing the PHP part of the source code regarding the problem :

[image]

It would be nice, if datasource were working with cell references too, because once the generated XLSX file, if I could open it and modify the referenced cell value, the chart will automatically update showing the new situation.

Your help would be much appreciated.